# How can I open a writeable stream to a new csv file in AWS S3 to use it inside the cycle?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

Can someone help me to find the way to open a stream directly into S3 to write some data into s3? I use .Net 7 and the main idea is to reduce local memory usage by getting small batches of data (1000 rows by page) from db using EF in cycle and write each batch into the same csv file in s3. Let's assume I have 1 million rows in a table and I want to write them all into s3 csv file so I want to open a stream and start iterating through all of the rows in db, taking 1000 rows per iteration and writing them into s3. Thanks a lot in advance!!

I tried to use PutObjectRequestbut have no clue how to implement partial writing (write each batch at the same file in s3) using this class

P.s. need smthng like this (this code doesn't work):

```
        int pageSize = 100;
        int pageNumber = 1;
        bool hasMoreDocuments = true;
        using var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);//AmazonS3Client
        using var s3Stream = await transferUtility.OpenStreamAsync(_bucketName, path);
        while (hasMoreDocuments)
        {
            var pagedDocuments = await query //IQueryable
                .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToListAsync();

            using var writer = new StreamWriter(s3Stream);
            foreach (var doc in pagedDocuments)
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(ConvertToCsvRow(doc));
            }
            writer.Flush();

            if (pagedDocuments.Count < pageSize)
            {
                hasMoreDocuments = false;
            }

            pageNumber++;
        }
```

Comment: An Http client the connection closes after each request/response so you cannot break message into pieces.  It may be better to use a WebSocket where multiple request/response can occur without closing the connection.  See : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: You can create your own `Stream` class to use in `StreamContent`, and it can  lazily pull whatever data it needs on the go. Please show relevant code

Comment: @Charlieface added some details, please take a look